# How can I use Python strings so that the same code works in 2.6, 2.7, 3.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to write some simple Python scripts that can be used unmodified on different Python versions, but I'm having trouble with strings...

```
text = get_data()  
phrases = [ "Soggarth Eogham O'Growney ,克尔・德怀尔", "capitis #3 病态上升涨大的繁殖性勃现", "IsoldeIsult、第一任威尔士亲王" ]  
for item in phrases:  
    if item not in text:  **# 3.3 ok.  2.7 UnicodeDecodeError**
        print ("Expected phrase '" + item + "' not found")
```

The code above works in 3.3.  When I try to run it under 2.7 I get

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is easily fixed by changing the first line to

```
text = get_data().encode('utf-8')
```

But then, this does not work on 3.3.  Any way to make this work with one version of the source code?
Python noob.

Comment: You can always check `sys.version_info.major` and only call `encode()` when it's less than `3`.

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/pyporting.html and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/

Comment: Also change second line to `phrases = [ u"Soggarth Eogham O'Growney ,克尔・德怀尔", u"capitis #3 病态上升涨大的繁殖性勃现", u"IsoldeIsult、第一任威尔士亲王" ]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `get_data()` will return Unicode strings. You get the error because you concatenate the Unicode string with a 8-bit string, forcing a conversion, which will by default be done with the ASCII codec, and since the data contains non-ascii characters, this fails.

The best way to get the above code to work is to then make sure that all your strings are Unicode, by prefixing them with u"":

```
phrases = [ u"Soggarth Eogham O'Growney ,克尔・德怀尔", 
            u"capitis #3 病态上升涨大的繁殖性勃现", 
            u"IsoldeIsult、第一任威尔士亲王" ]
```

However, this will will only work in Python 2.x and Python 3.3. If you need to use Python 3.2 or 3.1, you need to have a method that will make it into Unicode under Python 2, but will do nothing under Python 3 (as it already is Unicode there).

Such a function is typically called `u()`, and you can define it like this:

```
import sys
if sys.version < '3':
    import codecs
    def u(x):
        return codecs.unicode_escape_decode(x)[0]
else:
    def u(x):
        return x
```

Comment: The 'u' in front of the strings worked for me.  I have found that "from \_\_future\_\_ import unicode_literals" at the top of the file had the same effect.

Comment: @bluedog: Indeed it does, but it also makes it hard to have *non*-unicode strings, making it less useful.